# How to release an AWS elastic IP with ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, ansible-2.x, elastic-ip

I am following the ansible documentation here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ec2_eip_module.html in order to provision an ec2 instance with a new elastic IP. The parameter `release_on_disassociation` is `set` to yes but after the disassociation the elastic IP is not released.

First, I created the ec2 with the elastic IP:

```
- name: provision new instances with ec2
  ec2:
    keypair: mykey
    instance_type: c1.medium
    image: ami-40603AD1
    wait: yes
    group: webserver
    count: 3
  register: ec2

- name: associate new elastic IPs with each of the instances
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: "{{ item }}"
    release_on_disassociation: yes
  loop: "{{ ec2.instance_ids }}"
```

Afterwards, the elastic IP is disassociated:

```
- name: Gather EC2 facts
  ec2_instance_facts:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    filters:
      "tag:Type": "{{ server_type }}"
  register: ec2
- name: disassociate an elastic IP with a device
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: '{{ item.instance_id }}'
    ip: '{{ item.public_ip_address }}'
    state: absent
  when: item.public_ip_address is defined
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

ansible --version

```
ansible 2.8.4
```

Python Version is 3.7.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought perhaps `release_on_disassociation:` was an AWS feature, but even if it is then it doesn't matter for your case because the module does not examine that parameter during `state: present` actions. Rather it only consults that parameter [during `state: absent`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.8.4/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/ec2_eip.py#L445)

So I believe you need to move that parameter from the top `ec2_eip` down to the bottom one:

```
- name: disassociate an elastic IP with a device
  ec2_eip:
    device_id: '{{ item.instance_id }}'
    ip: '{{ item.public_ip_address }}'
    release_on_disassociation: yes
    state: absent
  when: item.public_ip_address is defined
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```